# Excel Macro using the replace function between sheets

Tags: vba, excel, replace

I have a list of numbers on sheet1(tblparts), the numbers are in the range of A2:A3900.

I have a list of those numbers with corresponding manufacturers on sheet2(sheet1), the range should be A2:1390 (manufactures names) and B2:1390 (manufacturers numbers). I need to replace the numbers on tblparts with manufacturers name from sheet1.

I keep getting a "run-time error 424" :Object required on line 10.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim i As Integer
Dim FindStr As String
Dim RepStr As String

For i = 2 To 1390
FindStr = Sheet1.Range("B" & i).Value
RepStr = Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value

tblParts.Range("A:A").Cells.Replace What:=FindStr, Replacement:=RepStr
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined in your macro what `tblParts` is and you must set it using `Set`, since it's a complex object and not a primitive.

For example, the following should work assuming `tblParts` is defined and set to `"Sheet1"` in the active workbook:

```vb
Option Explicit ' Always a good idea!

Sub Macro1()

  Dim tblParts As Worksheet
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim FindStr As String
  Dim RepStr As String

  Set tblParts = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("tblparts")
  Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")

  For i = 2 To 1390
    FindStr = Sht.Range("B" & i).Value
    RepStr = Sht.Range("A" & i).Value

    tblParts.Range("A:A").Cells.Replace What:=FindStr, Replacement:=RepStr
  Next i

End Sub
```

The `Option Explicit` at the top will force you to declare all your variables explicitly. If you don't, they're assumed to be of type `Variant`. But you're using a variant variable in your code to call its `Range` method, which doesn't exist, hence the error you're getting.

Comment: Thanks DJ, but now its getting tricky. I added the line Set tblparts = Worksheets("tblparts") and the error goes away but the replacement is not happening.

Comment: @NoNo: Good stuff. As for your replacement not happening, difficult to know what to suggest. The original question is answered but this part will need you to go through the code with the debugger and find out what's going on.

Comment: I modified it to this   Set tblParts = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("tblparts")
  Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1") and it started working :). Thank you